# ag-grid angular- some properties in column definitions (f.e. resizable) don't work

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I'm playing with ag-grid in Angular. I'd like to have some columns sortable and/or resizable and others not. I see in docs, that properties like *sortable* and *resizable* in columnDefs should work. But they don't. The only way I can make columns to be sortable and filterable is to add properties enableFilter and enableColResize in gridOptions like that:

```
gridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
      tooltip: (t: any) => { return t.value; }
    },
    overlayNoRowsTemplate: '<span></span>',
    overlayLoadingTemplate: '<span></span>',
    enableSorting:true,
    enableFilter: true,
    enableColResize: true,
    domLayout: 'normal'
  };

<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 335px;"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated()"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  animateRows
  rowSelection="single"
>
```

But when using that this way I'm not able to config specific columns to work the way I want it to work. Does anybody know, what's a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using an older version of ag-grid (19.1.4 or earlier). You can either update your version of ag-grid to 20.0.0 or newer by running the ***npm update*** command or you could use `suppressSorting`, `suppressFilter` and `resizable` properties in `columnDefs` which is the alternative for the same functionality in older versions, but you must first set `enableFilter` and `enableSorting` to **true** for *suppress sorting* and *suppress filter* to work.

Comment: I believe it's not true. I'm using 19.1.4 community version, which is pretty new and installed even now when I call npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-angular

Comment: but thanks for hint with those suppress[...] parameters

Comment: ag-grid version 20.0.0 was released on Jan 11 2019. You can check the change log here - https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=20.0.0. Update your package number to 20.0.0 and run the npm install. Or you can run the npm update command. The documentation in ag-grid website currently is for the 20.0.0 version. Documentation for the older versions can be found here - https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/

Comment: @RIPI colDef's properties sortable, reziable and filter were added part of Ag-grid 20.0.0. On 19.1.4 you can use gridOption's property enableSorting, enableFilter or enableColumnResize instead of the colDef's properties, and then use suppressSorting on the individual columns where sorting is not required.

Comment: thank to you both guys. I updated version of ag-grid-angular and ag-grid-community to 20.0.0 and it worked. But some functions like custom comparator in filterParams doesn't. I guess it can be problem with ag-grid dependency. In package.json I have version 18.1.2. and I get error ' No matching version found for ag-grid@^19.1.4'. I get the same thing when I'm trying to update to 20.0.0. Which version should I use to make it work? Or maybe ag-grid-angular and ag-grid-community are enough?

Comment: @RIPI I believe before verison 19, ag-grid-community was called just ag-grid. You can safely remove ag-grid from package.json file since you need only ag-grid-community and ag-grid-angular.